# WEB RTC, Peer JS and NAT

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I am writing a chat roulette.
Here is the link:
http://176.58.60.219:8181/rouletteChat/welcome.htm

I am using peer js, which is based on WEB RTC. Now connects using your wifi - everything works . I want to connect in the Moscow metro (there is a wifi). Not now connects .
I find on this page :
http://habrahabr.ru/company/toptechphoto/blog/203306/

```
    [{url:'stun:stun01.sipphone.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.ekiga.net'},
{url:'stun:stun.fwdnet.net'},
{url:'stun:stun.ideasip.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.iptel.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se'},
{url:'stun:stun.schlund.de'},
{url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stunserver.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.softjoys.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voiparound.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voipbuster.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voipstunt.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voxgratia.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.xten.com'},
{
    url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
    credential: 'muazkh',
    username: 'webrtc@live.com
'
},
{
    url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
    credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
    username: '28224511:1379330808'
},
{
    url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
    credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
    username: '28224511:1379330808'
}]
```

But it did not help . Looks may need to add some more line . Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

These STUN and TURN servers are public. So nobody make sure that it works.
Now we use following iceServers:

```
{url:'stun:stun01.sipphone.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.ekiga.net'},
{url:'stun:stun.fwdnet.net'},
{url:'stun:stun.ideasip.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.iptel.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se'},
{url:'stun:stun.schlund.de'},
{url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stunserver.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.softjoys.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voiparound.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voipbuster.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voipstunt.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voxgratia.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.xten.com'},
{
    'url': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
    'credential': 'muazkh',
    'username': 'webrtc@live.com'
},
{
    'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
    'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
    'username': '28224511:1379330808'
},
{
    'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
    'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
    'username': '28224511:1379330808'
}
```

It works for so well. Please follow the links below to understand how STUN/TURN works
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/?redirect_from_locale=ru
http://www.slideshare.net/Audiocod/nat-traversal-in-webrtc-context

If you want be sure about resolving NAT problems you can run your own STUN and TURN servers.

Comment: the turn servers are not "public" and if you check the credentials you'll notice that they don't even work anymore.

Comment: Me need help with that problem. For money. Can somebody?
My email - stim_alex@mail.ru